# Show a ProgressDialog when user triggers activity start (button press)

Tags: android

I have a class which extends `Activity` this class job is to get some data from a `SQLite` database on the phone, and init. a `ListView` with all the data from the database.

This is the method for getting information from the database:

```
public ArrayList<Case> getFromDatabase() {

    ArrayList<Case> c = db1.getAllContacts();    
    return c; 
}
```

As earlier mentioned this method is inside a class that extends `Activity` This method is called in the `onCreate` method. This operation takes about 2 second if the database contains around 15 records. How can I show a ProgressDialog, when user presses the button to start this activity, just to show that something is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create ProgressDialog as field of the activity by declaring an ProgressDialog variable outside onCreate method:

```
ProgressDialog pd=null;
```

Create a Handler as field in Activty, by writing following block outside of onCreate method.

```
Handler handler=new Handler()
{
   public void handleMessage(Message msg)
   {
      pd.dismiss();
      //do other operations on EventThread.
      ArrayList<Case> c= (ArrayList<Case>)msg.obj;
      //Process c
   }
}
```

now in onCreate method replace your code with following:

```
pd=ProgressDialog.show(YourActivity.this, "title", "subtitle");
Thread thread=new Thread()
{
   public void run()
   {
       ArrayList<Case> c = db1.getAllContacts();
       Message msg=handler.obtainMessage();
       msg.obj=c;
       handler.sendMessage(msg);
   }
};
thread.start();
```

Comment: Remember that the method for getting data from the database has to return the ArrayList, which is not possible by this example.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you wrap your database in a ContentProvider and then use a CursorLoader to power the ListActivity.  This will avoid tying up your UI thread, avoid the need for a progress bar, take care of updating the list when the database contents change, and more.  (If you just want your contacts from the device, there is a [Contacts Content Provider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/contacts-provider.html) already.)

Answer (score 0):

Use AsyncTask to show ProgressDialog and fetch data in background.

```
new FetchRSSFeeds().execute();
```

And then create class

```
private class FetchRSSFeeds extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

 private ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(HomeActivity.this);

    /** progress dialog to show user that the backup is processing. */
    /** application context. */

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        this.dialog.setMessage("Please wait");
        this.dialog.show();
    }

    protected Boolean doInBackground(final String... args) {
        try {

            /**
             * Fetch the data
             */
            Utilities.arrayRSS = objRSSFeed.FetchRSSFeeds(Constants.Feed_URL);
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("tag", "error", e);
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {

        if (dialog.isShowing()) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }

          // Setting data to list adaptar
          setListData();
          txtTitle.setText(Utilities.RSSTitle);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not the way I want to do this. Iam familiar with the AsyncTask, but this wont solve my problem. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to do that. Basically lookup and use AsyncTask

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html

Answer (score 0):

Use an [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). This class provides methods for solving the problem you are facing.

First, in the `onPreExecute()` method you can start a `ProgressDialog` (the code you write here, will be executed on the thread you create the `AsyncTask` object, i.e. the UI thread in your case)

Then, in the `doInBackground()` method you load al your data from the DB.

And lastly, in the `onPostExecute()` method you have the results from the background thread, you can dismiss here the `ProgressDialog`, since you are again on the UI thread.

Additional information can be found [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html).